# How do I generate more values in each column?

Tags: java

I need help to see what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to generate 10 random values in 3 columns, but so far I can only generate one.

```
    private static void displayDifficultyScore(ArrayList<TestDive> alist, double[] dArray)
    {

        // Create a Random class
        Random rand = new Random();
        double[] diffScores = new double[10];
        double[] diffArray = new double[3];
         
        
        // Print next line
        System.out.println();       
         
         
        // Loop for Difficulty Scores
        for (int j = 0; j < diffScores.length; j++) {
            diffScores[j] = 2.0 + rand.nextDouble() * 3.0;
            System.out.printf("%-7.1f%n", diffScores[j]);
        }
        
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] diffScores = new double[1];
        ArrayList<TestDive> alist = new ArrayList<TestDive>();
        for (int j = 0; j < diffScores.length; j++) {
            displayDifficultyScore(alist, diffScores);
        }
    }
}
```

Currently it's only printing out in 1 column:

```
2.9
4.4
4.9
3.7
4.3 
3.1 
4.2 
4.5 
4.2 
2.9
```

Output that I want to achieve:

```
2.9    3.0    2.2
4.4    3.4    4.7
4.9    2.5    3.0
3.7    4.7    3.3
4.3    4.4    3.8
3.1    3.0    4.9
4.2    2.1    2.9
4.5    5.0    2.2
4.2    4.8    3.6
2.9    2.6    3.1
```

Comment: You probably want a multi-dimensional array instead of two separate arrays, along with some nested loops.  You could [start with this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidimensional-arrays-in-java/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try generating a 2D array (or matrix) first and then printing it

Something like this

```java
public class Hello {
    private static double[][] generateDifficultyScores(int matrixLength, int matrixWidth) {
        // Create a Random class
        Random     rand       = new Random();
        double[][] diffScores = new double[matrixLength][matrixWidth];

        // Loop for Difficulty Scores
        for (int i = 0; i < matrixLength; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrixWidth; j++) {
                diffScores[i][j] = 2.0 + rand.nextDouble() * 3.0;
            }
        }

        return diffScores;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // generate random difficulty scores (stores it in a 2D array or matrix of values)
        double[][] diffScores = generateDifficultyScores(10, 3);

        // print out each array in matrix (line by line)
        for (int j = 0; j < diffScores.length; j++) {
            // print each element of the array separated by a tab `\t` and formatted to one decimal point
            System.out.printf("%7.1f\t%7.1f\t%7.1f", diffScores[j][0], diffScores[j][1], diffScores[j][2]);

            // add a newline for next iteration
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```